# How to make Enum proc specific Bools

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I have an EnumProperty (a list) which enables the visibility of three different collections and now I want it to enable different Bools based on what's selected from the list. I can share my example - blend file if possible. For instance, below, I need the cube Bool to appear only when "skin1" is selected from the enum.

````
import math
import json
import collections
import traceback
from math import pi
from bpy.props import StringProperty
from mathutils import Euler, Matrix, Quaternion, Vector
from rna_prop_ui import rna_idprop_quote_path

rig_id = "Character"

#### CUSTOM PROPERTIES ####

#### SKIN LIST #####

character_skin_list = [('skin1','Skin 1',''),
                         ('skin2','Skin 2',''),
                         ('skin3','Skin 3','')
                        ]                   

def skin_show_update(self, context):
    
            
    for skin1 in character_skin_list:
        bpy.data.collections[skin1[0]].hide_viewport = not self.show_skin == skin1[0]
               
     
    return
 
 
bpy.types.Armature.show_skin = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = character_skin_list,
                                                        name = "Skin",
                                                        description = "Select skin",
                                                        update = skin_show_update)


#### CUBE ####

def cube_show_update(self, context):
    
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"].hide_viewport = not self.show_cube
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"].hide_render = not self.show_cube

    
    return

bpy.types.Armature.show_cube = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default = True,
                                                            name = "Cube",
                                                            description = "Show cube",
                                                            update = cube_show_update)

#### SPHERE ####
                                                            
def sphere_show_update(self, context):
    
    bpy.data.objects["Sphere"].hide_viewport = not self.show_sphere
    bpy.data.objects["Sphere"].hide_render = not self.show_sphere

    
    return

bpy.types.Armature.show_sphere = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default = True,
                                                            name = "Sphere",
                                                            description = "Show sphere",
                                                            update = sphere_show_update)
                                                            
#### TORUS ####
                                                            
def torus_show_update(self, context):
    
    bpy.data.objects["Torus"].hide_viewport = not self.show_torus
    bpy.data.objects["Torus"].hide_render = not self.show_torus

    
    return

bpy.types.Armature.show_torus = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default = True,
                                                            name = "Torus",
                                                            description = "Show torus",
                                                            update = torus_show_update)                                                            

                                                            
#### TOGGLES ####

class RigLayersProperties(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Properties"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_rig_layers_properties_" + rig_id
    bl_category = 'Item'

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        try:
            return (context.active_object.data.get("rig_id") == rig_id)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return False

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        
        row = col.row()
        row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'show_skin', toggle=True)
        
        col.separator()

        row = col.row()
        row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'show_cube', toggle=True)
                
        row = col.row()
        row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'show_sphere', toggle=True)  
        
        row = col.row()
        row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'show_torus', toggle=True) 
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RigLayersProperties)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RigLayersProperties)
register()                                                                  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure you're looking for that, but if each skin enum is linked to a bool property, you can do it like this. It's a little hacky usage of a dictionary, but it's basically a switch instruction.

```
def draw(self, context):
    data = context.active_object.data
    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column()
    
    row = col.row()
    row.prop(data , 'show_skin', toggle=True)
    
    col.separator()

    bool_to_show = {
        "skin1": "show_cube",
        "skin2": "show_sphere",
        "skin3": "show_torus",
    }.get(data.show_skin)

    row = col.row()
    row.prop(data , bool_to_show , toggle=True)
```

However if the logic is more involved than that, eg if you want layout elements to be displayed when 2 different options are selected but not the other one, you can use conditional statements :

```
def draw(self, context):
    data = context.active_object.data
    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column()
    
    row = col.row()
    row.prop(data , 'show_skin', toggle=True)
    
    col.separator()

    if data.show_skin in ("skin1", "skin2"):
        row = col.row()
        row.prop(data, 'show_cube', toggle=True)
            
    if data.show_skin in ("skin2", "skin3"):
        row = col.row()
        row.prop(data, 'show_sphere', toggle=True)  
    
    if data.show_skin in ("skin3", "skin1"):
        row = col.row()
        row.prop(data, 'show_torus', toggle=True)
```

Comment: Ah nice, it works (both ways!) :) Thank you! (I'm new user, hence site won't let me upvote).